# jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, chrome-web-driver

I would like to automate my JMeter recorded scripts using **jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config** to execute in chrome tab. Is there any way to run my recorded script in Chrome Driver Config without using javascript in **jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler ?**.

I am using Apache JMeter 3.2 version and for reference I have attached screenshot of my Test Plan, please verify it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter acts on [HTTP protocol level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) so it is not possible to convert recorded HTTP requests into full browser tests. You can [convert existing Selenium tests into JMeter ones](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter), but not in the opposite direction.

You can try using i.e. [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) to record your UI-based scenario, export it to Java language and use them as a basis for your [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) based scripts (it supports variety of languages), however you will still need to amend the recorded script as the code, generated by Selenium IDE won't be consumed by the WebDriver Sampler "as is"

Comment: That should be fine, I can try using Selenium IDE to run UI based execution. Thanks for your suggestion.